# SQL: Assembling Non-Overlapping Sets

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have sets of consecutive integers, organized by `type`, in `table1`.  All values are between `1` and `10`, inclusive.

```
table1:
row_id  set_id  type    min_value   max_value
1       1       a       1           3
2       2       a       4           10
3       3       a       6           10
4       4       a       2           5
5       5       b       1           9
6       6       c       1           7
7       7       c       3           10
8       8       d       1           2
9       9       d       3           3
10      10      d       4           5
11      11      d       7           10
```

In `table2`, within each `type`, I want to assemble all possible **maximal**, **non-overlapping** sets (though gaps that cannot be filled by any `set`s of the correct `type` are okay).  Desired output:

```
table2:
row_id  type    group_id    set_id
1       a       1           1
2       a       1           2
3       a       2           1
4       a       2           3
5       a       3           3
6       a       3           4
7       b       4           5
8       c       5           6
9       c       6           7
10      d       7           8
11      d       7           9
12      d       7           10
13      d       7           11
```

My current idea is to use the fact that there is a limited number of possible values.  Steps:

1. Find all sets in `table1` containing value `1`.  Copy them into `table2`.
2. Find all sets in `table1` containing value `2` and not already in `table2`.
3. Join the sets from (2) with `table1` on `type`, `set_id`, and having `min_value` greater than the `group`'s greatest `max_value`.
4. For the sets from (2) that did not join in (3), insert them into `table2`.  These start new `group`s that may be extended later.
5. Repeat steps (2) through (4) for `value`s `3` through `10`.

I think this will work, but it has a lot of pain-in-the-butt steps, especially for (2)--finding the sets not in `table2`, and (4)--finding the sets that did not join.

Do you know a faster, more efficient method?  My real data has millions of `set`s, thousands of `type`s, and hundreds of `value`s (though fortunately, as in the example, the `value`s are bounded), so scalability is essential.

I'm using PLSQL Developer with Oracle 10g (not 11g as I stated before--thanks, IT department).  Thanks!

Comment: Your example only has results that have two elements.  Can there be more than two?

Comment: Yes!  That was just for simplicity.  It may be that every `value` from `1` to `10` is a separate set, and thus a separate element.  I'll update the sample data to show this.

Comment: I think your process is fine, except for steps 1 and 2.  You can just initialize the table with each set in table1.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid all of the fiddly little steps involved here, but if there's no magic simple solution, then okay.  Thanks for looking it over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Oracle 10g you can't use recursive CTEs, but with a bit of work you can do something similar with the `connect by` syntax. First you need to generate a CTE or in-line view which has all the non-overlapping links, which you can do with:

```
select t1.type, t1.set_id, t1.min_value, t1.max_value,
  t2.set_id as next_set_id, t2.min_value as next_min_value,
  t2.max_value as next_max_value,
  row_number() over (order by t1.type, t1.set_id, t2.set_id) as group_id
from table1 t1
left join table1 t2 on t2.type = t1.type
and t2.min_value > t1.max_value
where not exists (
  select 1
  from table1 t4
  where t4.type = t1.type
  and t4.min_value > t1.max_value
  and t4.max_value < t2.min_value
)
order by t1.type, group_id, t1.set_id, t2.set_id;
```

This took a bit of experimentation and it's certainly possible I've missed or lost something about the rules in the process; but that gives you 12 pseudo-rows, and is in my previous answer this allows the two separate chains starting with `a/1` to be followed while constraining the `d` values to a single chain:

```
TYPE SET_ID  MIN_VALUE  MAX_VALUE NEXT_SET_ID NEXT_MIN_VALUE NEXT_MAX_VALUE GROUP_ID
---- ------ ---------- ---------- ----------- -------------- -------------- --------
a         1          1          3           2              4             10        1 
a         1          1          3           3              6             10        2 
a         2          4         10                                                  3 
a         3          6         10                                                  4 
a         4          2          5           3              6             10        5 
b         5          1          9                                                  6 
c         6          1          7                                                  7 
c         7          3         10                                                  8 
d         8          1          2           9              3              3        9 
d         9          3          3          10              4              5       10 
d        10          4          5          11              7             10       11 
d        11          7         10                                                 12
```

And that can be used as a CTE; querying that with a connect-by loop:

```
with t as (
   ... -- same as above query
)
select t1.type,
  dense_rank() over (partition by null
    order by connect_by_root group_id) as group_id,
  t1.set_id
from t t1
connect by type = prior type
and set_id = prior next_set_id
start with not exists (
  select 1 from table1 t2
  where t2.type = t1.type
  and t2.max_value < t1.min_value
)
and not exists (
  select 1 from t t3
  where t3.type = t1.type
  and t3.next_max_value < t1.next_min_value
)
order by t1.type, group_id, t1.min_value;
```

The `dense_rank()` makes the group IDs contiguous; not sure if you actually need those at all, or if their sequence matters, so it's optional really. `connect_by_root` gives the group ID for the start of the chain, so although there were 12 rows and 12 `group_id` values in the initial query, they don't all appear in the final result.

The connection is via two `prior` values, type and the next set ID found in the initial query. That creates all the chains, but own its own would also include shorter chains - for `d` you'd see `8,9,10,11` but also `9,10,11` and `10,11`, which you don't want as separate groups. Those are eliminated by the `start with` conditions, which could maybe be simplified.

That gives:

```
TYPE GROUP_ID SET_ID
---- -------- ------
a           1      1 
a           1      2 
a           2      1 
a           2      3 
a           3      4 
a           3      3 
b           4      5 
c           5      6 
c           6      7 
d           7      8 
d           7      9 
d           7     10 
d           7     11
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8f817/4).

Comment: Brilliant, elegant, and easily scaled to my large dataset.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you can identify all the groups and their starting `set_id` then you can use a recursive approach and do this all in a single statement, rather than needing to populate a table iteratively. However you'd need to benchmark both approaches both for speed/efficiency and resource consumption - whether it will scale for your data volumes and within your system's available resources would need to be verified.

If I understand when you decide to start a new group you can identify them all at once with a query like:

```
with t as (
  select t1.type, t1.set_id, t1.min_value, t1.max_value,
    t2.set_id as next_set_id, t2.min_value as next_min_value,
    t2.max_value as next_max_value
  from table1 t1
  left join table1 t2 on t2.type = t1.type and t2.min_value > t1.max_value
  where not exists (
    select 1
    from table1 t3
    where t3.type = t1.type
    and t3.max_value < t1.min_value
  )
)
select t.type, t.set_id, t.min_value, t.max_value,
  t.next_set_id, t.next_min_value, t.next_max_value,
  row_number() over (order by t.type, t.min_value, t.next_min_value) as grp_id
from t
where not exists (
  select 1 from t t2
  where t2.type = t.type
  and t2.next_max_value < t.next_min_value
)
order by grp_id;
```

The tricky bit here is getting all three groups for `a`, specifically the two groups that start with `set_id = 1`, but only one group for `d`. The inner select (in the CTE) looks for sets that don't have a lower non-overlapping range via the `not exists` clause, and outer-joins to the same table to get the next set(s) that don't overlap, which gives you two groups that start with `set_id = 1`, but also four that start with `set_id = 9`. The outer select then ignores everything but the lowest non-overlapping with a second `not exists` clause - but doesn't have to hit the real table again.

So that gives you:

```
TYPE SET_ID  MIN_VALUE  MAX_VALUE NEXT_SET_ID NEXT_MIN_VALUE NEXT_MAX_VALUE GRP_ID
---- ------ ---------- ---------- ----------- -------------- -------------- ------
a         1          1          3           2              4             10      1 
a         1          1          3           3              6             10      2 
a         4          2          5           3              6             10      3 
b         5          1          9                                                4 
c         6          1          7                                                5 
c         7          3         10                                                6 
d         8          1          2           9              3              3      7
```

You can then use that as the anchor member in a [recursive subquery factoring clause](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/statements_10002.htm#BCEJGIBG):

```
with t as (
  ...
),
r (type, set_id, min_value, max_value,
    next_set_id, next_min_value, next_max_value, grp_id) as (
  select t.type, t.set_id, t.min_value, t.max_value,
    t.next_set_id, t.next_min_value, t.next_max_value,
    row_number() over (order by t.type, t.min_value, t.next_min_value)
  from t
  where not exists (
    select 1 from t t2
    where t2.type = t.type
    and t2.next_max_value < t.next_min_value
  )
  ...
```

If you left the `r` CTE with that and just did `sleect * from r` you'd get the same seven groups.

The recursive member then uses the *next* `set_id` and its range from that query as the next member of each group, and repeats the outer join/not-exists look up to find the next set(s) again; stopping when there is no next non-overlapping set:

```
  ...
  union all
  select r.type, r.next_set_id, r.next_min_value, r.next_max_value,
    t.set_id, t.min_value, t.max_value, r.grp_id
  from r
  left join table1 t
  on t.type = r.type
  and t.min_value > r.next_max_value
  and not exists (
    select 1 from table1 t2
    where t2.type = r.type
    and t2.min_value > r.next_max_value
    and t2.max_value < t.min_value
  )
  where r.next_set_id is not null -- to stop looking when you reach a leaf node
)
...
```

Finally you have a query based on the recursive CTE to get the columns you want and to specify the order:

```
...
select r.type, r.grp_id, r.set_id
from r
order by r.type, r.grp_id, r.min_value;
```

Which gets:

```
TYPE     GRP_ID     SET_ID
---- ---------- ----------
a             1          1 
a             1          2 
a             2          1 
a             2          3 
a             3          4 
a             3          3 
b             4          5 
c             5          6 
c             6          7 
d             7          8 
d             7          9 
d             7         10 
d             7         11
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8f817/1).

If you wanted to you could show the min/max values for each set, and could track and show the min/max value for each group. I've just show then columns from the question though.

Comment: This looks really great!  Unfortunately, after several hours of trying to get it to work, I realized my IT was wrong about the version--really it's 10g.  Is there any way to translate this to 10g, since the recursive subquery factoring is new for 11gR2?